# np.array(img_data_list) :TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, classification

```
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)

def getLabel(id):
    return ['anger','contempt','disgust','fear','happy','sadness','surprise'][id]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23/853380379.py in <module>
    21     plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    22     plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

---> 23     plt.ylabel('prediction = %s' % getLabel(res[i]), fontsize=14)
24 # show the plot
25 plt.show()

/tmp/ipykernel_23/431880561.py in getLabel(id)
15
16 def getLabel(id):
---> 17     return ['anger','contempt','disgust','fear','happy','sadness','surprise'][id]

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.